# Joining flv files produces much larger output

Tags: video, flv

I have three flv files around 30 Mb each. I joined them together using mencoder on Linux with

> mencoder -forceidx -ovc copy -oac pcm -o output.flv input1.flv input2.flv input3.flv

The video codec is H.264 and the audio is MPEG-4 AAC.

The resulting file is 390Mb.

Is there a way to join flv files on Linux without this file size increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I progressively discovered what the problem was.

using the `-oac pcm` option was rencoding the audio without compression.

It was not possible to use `-oac copy -fafmttag 0x706D` due to slight differences in the audio bit rate.

Using `-oac mp3lame` reduced the file size but a bit rate higher than the original was being used.

Using `-oac mp3lame -lameopts vbr=3:br=96` I got a file with a size equivalent to the sum of the three original files. I did not check if the sound quality is the same or not.

Comment: That is what my next suggestion would have been ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the increase is that you are converting the audio to uncompressed PCM: `-oac pcm`.

Try this instead:

```
mencoder -forceidx -ovc copy -oac copy -o output.flv input1.flv input2.flv input3.flv
```

Comment: I already tried it but got this error: `Audio format 0x4134504d is incompatible with '-oac copy', please try '-oac pcm' instead or use '-fafmttag' to override it.`

Comment: Well, the pcm command is the reason it is increasing in size. Have you tried the other alternative it suggested?

Comment: I tried adding the option but got an error message: `The fafmttag option must be an integer: -o`. I got partial succes with `-oac mp3lame`: the file size went down to 127 Mb, still bigger than the original, though.

Comment: Try ` -fafmttag 0x706D `

Comment: Tried that. It tells me that -oac copy can only be done when the different files have the same codec. According to the details of the 3 files they do have the same audio codec.

Comment: There must be some small difference in the codecs. Can you update the question with the info of each of the 3 files

Comment: it seems the ID_AUDIO_BITRATE of the files is different, so -oac copy wont work.